# Awk Sed Grep parsing text file to match a pattern

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I need to  run this from command prompt to display only those lines that match the pattern after the words beside the sign#  Example #IP.
So if I'm looking for IP, I want to print the lines under the section #IP.
In this case I will print only 3 lines. This is a large file and has lots of sections starting with #.

Can you kindly help with this request?

```
#IP Source 
1  is for 1
2  is for 2
3  3 for 3
#BASE
4 is for 4
5 is for 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with GNU sed:

```
sed -n '/IP/,/#/{/#/d;p;}' file
```

Output:

```
1  is for 1
2  is for 2
3  3 for 3
```

Comment: I tried to replace the /BASE/ is above with the $1 so  Ican pass the parameter to search for . .but it's not working. .Any idea?

Comment: Replace `BASE` by `'"$1"'` to interrupt single quotes and use `"`.

Comment: Hi Cyrus I tried that tha tdid not work. My idea was to put this command as an alias in the .bashrc     so alias ho='sed -n '/"$1"/,/#/{/#/d;p;}' /etc/hosts' .. but that does not work at all .I tried it in an regular executable and tha tdid not work either

Comment: sed -n '/'$1'/,/#/{/#/d;p;}' /etc/hosts  << this worked fine ,,  However I tried to assign it to an alias .. but getting error keeps saying wrong directory/file

Comment: This is not possible with an alias. Add a function to your .bashrc: `function foo() { sed -n '/'"$1"'/,/#/{/#/d;p;}' /etc/hosts; }`. Use it this way: `foo BASE`.

Comment: I was wondering why you are using `BASE` instead of `IP`. I guess it is just a typo. However, plus one for your attempt. Looks good! :)

Comment: @hek2mgl: Thank you for this hint. It was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an awk solution:

```
awk '/^#IP/{f=1;next} /^#/{f=0} f{print}' file
```

Some explanations of each *condition* { *action* } pair:

`/^#IP/{f=1;next}` - if the line starts with `#IP`, set variable `f` to 1 (true), then (`next`) skip further processing of this line.

`/^#/{f=0}` - if the line starts with a `#`, set variable `f` to 0 (false)

`f{print}` - if the variable `f` is true (not empty and not 0), print the current line.